# Strongly convex, bounded from below by a quadratic function.

Tags: convex-analysis

A strongly convex function $V: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with negative parameter is given, i.e.

$$
V(tx + (1-t)y) \leq tV(x) + (1-t) V(y) - \lambda t(1-t) | x -y |^2 ,
$$
with $\lambda<0$.
Why is then $V$ bounded from below by a quadratic function?

---

I considered the cases $x=y$ and $x=-y$, but I do not know how to go on.

Comment: Are you sure that the question is right? What mean $\ge$ in $\mathbb R^d$?I think your mind is: $||V(tx+(1−t)y)||\ge t||V(x)||+(1-t)||V(y)||-λt(1−t)||x−y||^2$

Comment: Oh, I am sorry! My first question, and immediately my first mistake! The function is of course real valued.

Comment: No. the question is right. I'm sorry. I made a mistake that $V:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$

Comment: I just edited it :)

Comment: if we put: $t=\frac12$ and $x=y$ what we get?

Comment: Then the quadratic term vanishes, I think. I also tried to set x=-y. But I do not know how to go on. But thank you, Agha kamali :)

Comment: The sum $V(x)+c|x|^2$ will be convex for suitable $c>0$, and therefore bounded below by a linear function.

Comment: @JeanValjean: Is the norm in your question, Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: @hamidkamali yes, it is.

Comment: I think you can solve the question similar this question: [prove this is a strongly convex function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103683/prove-this-is-a-strongly-convex-function?rq=1)

Comment: @JeanValjean: Do you get the solution?

Comment: Oh, yes thank you, I just got it! Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof for completeness (compiling the comments). Let $f(x)=-2\lambda\|x\|^2$. Then $f$ is [strongly convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103683/147263) with parameter $-\lambda>0$. Therefore, $V+f$ is convex. It follows that the graph of $V+f$ lies above any of its tangent planes. So, $V+f$ is bounded from below by a linear function $L$, and thus $V\ge L-f$.